# Is there a way to not return a cell after a condition in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working with a UITableView and want to add a conditional statement inside the `cellForRowAt` function to decide whether or not I should return a cell.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // Here is where I add the code to calculate which cells should appear, though it's not important for this example

  if  condition {
    return cell
  } 
}
```

But the error message I get is `Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'`

Is there a way I can not return something?

Comment: Better check condition in `numberOfRowsInSection` , Because you have to return Cell in `cellForRowAt` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that the only acceptable solution is to do that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Here is where I add the code to calculate which cells should appear, though it's not important for this example

    if condition {
        return cell
    } 

    // return empty cell
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can not return something?

Even though this is not a best practice - yes, you can silence this Xcode compile-time error message by using a fatal error:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // Here is where I add the code to calculate which cells should appear, though it's not important for this example

  if condition {
    return cell
  } 

  fatalError()
}
```

But in case if for some reason `condition` is false - the app will crash, so be aware of that.

In order to get more context from fatal error - you can pass a string to it describing what has happened, e.g:

```
fatalError("Condition Is Invalid, Failed Returning a Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to always return a cell.

If you need to suppress cells, better do so in the data source methods, like `numberOfRowsInSection`.